# Get interval between two distances python

Tags: python, pandas

In Python I have a pandas Dataframe with `pk1` as starting point and `pk2` as end point that I round up/down to the 200m closest. (pk1: 8140 -> 8000 ; pk2 8180 -> 8200)

I would like to have a list of each interval between all those distance like if I have a row with:

```
row1 pk1 = 8000 ; pk2 = 8200 -> [8000, 8200]
row2 pk1 = 8000 ; pk2 = 8600 -> [8000, 8200, 8000, 8200, 8400, 8600]
...
```

I can have duplicate that I will delete with a set.

I struggle to find a "pandas way" to do it.

Comment: I'm unclear on the desired result.  This isn't a "PANDAS way" problem, as stated.  You extract the two elevations, round as you've stated, and then make a list from a trivial `range` expression.

Comment: It's not clear to me how you get from your input to your second example.

Comment: second exemple is the value from the first row + all the value from the second... and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly this is what you want. I don't think there is any elegant way outside of using `apply` but I might be wrong.

```
print(df)

    pk1   pk2
0  8000  8200
1  8000  8600

def ranger(row):
    r = range(row['pk1'], row['pk2'] + 200, 200)
    return list(r)

df.assign(range=df.apply(ranger, axis=1))

    pk1   pk2                     range
0  8000  8200              [8000, 8200]
1  8000  8600  [8000, 8200, 8400, 8600]
```

To get all unique values you can do:

```
s = set()

for item in df.range.to_list():
    s.update(item)

print(sorted(s))

[8000, 8200, 8400, 8600]
```

Comment: Very close from what I'm expected. How then can I get all unique value from each list like here I finnaly need `my_list = [8000, 8200, 8400, 8600]`
Or better in a Series